# How do I connect to the internet during a Linux Mint CD install?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ethernet, setup

I am trying to install Linux Mint on my computer, MacBook Pro through via a dual boot setup. I’m at the point where I need to install the Linux Mint OS. However, I need to be connected to the Internet to do this.

I’ve tried setting up the “Network Connection” with a wired connection, an Ethernet connection and with Wi-Fi. None of these have worked so far.

I’m guessing the wired connection should be the easiest to setup. It seems to have already existed after the installation CD boot itself up.

I tried connecting my Ethernet cable to the computer. Network settings was trying to connect, never did and keep retrying.

Comment: Assuming you have a Router set up for your internet, have you tried connecting the ethernet cable from your laptop to the Router?

Comment: Yes I did try that. Within "Network settings" I saw that it was connecting, then disconnecting and then it would loop back to attempting to connect and so on.